# how to handle dynamic changing xpath for multiple objects having same xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to select multiple objects having same xpath only last few value sin xpath changes

I tried to add contains for the first one and it worked . But I am adding same code for second object and it is not working . Can we do this with any other method ?

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//[contains(@id,'listbox')]/li")))`

THis worked for first element . Second xpath is also similat on same page only last 4 characters are different.

Actual XPath for both is `//*[@id="listbox1196"]/li`

If I use same code for  both elements , second one fails . Please suggest .

Comment: Please explain "fails"... Is it not found? How many `<li>` do you expect?

Comment: yes not found , so how to use regular expression for same path . first xpath  is //*[@id="listbox1196"]/li and second xpath is //*[@id="listbox2196"]/li . And both values after listbox gets changing dynamically

Comment: for first html is as below : <li b2b-dropdown-list-desktop="" b2b-key-item="" b2b-accessibility-click="13" aria-selected="true" data-hover="true" ng-class="{'awd-select-list-item': (isInputDropdown), 'module-list-item': (!isInputDropdown)}" tabindex="0" role="option" ng-click="selectDropdownItem()" ng-focus="highlightDropdown()" ng-repeat="d in ecdapp.comps" value="dcae" search-key="DCAE" class="ng-scope ng-binding awd-select-list-item">DCAE</li>

Comment: for second html is as below : <li b2b-dropdown-list-desktop="" b2b-key-item="" b2b-accessibility-click="13" aria-selected="true" data-hover="true" ng-class="{'awd-select-list-item': (isInputDropdown), 'module-list-item': (!isInputDropdown)}" tabindex="0" role="option" ng-click="selectDropdownItem()" ng-focus="highlightDropdown()" ng-repeat="d in ecdapp.apps" value="DCAE" search-key="DCAE" class="ng-scope ng-binding awd-select-list-item">DCAE</li>

Comment: Neither of those items you entered in comments contains an id of 'listbox'. In fact, they do not have an ID at all. Please edit your question to contain the complete HTML or there is no way to help.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is in the `wait`. You're asking for the "visibility Of **Element** Located`. *Singular*. But you're giving it a list.

When given a list, Selenium will always only look at the first record. So once the first element exists, the code continues and most likely causing at least one break.

Because you're dealing with a list, I asked in the comments if you knew ahead of time how many elements should exist. There is a condition called, `numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By locator, int min)`. So the first step would be to wait until most, or better yet all, of the `<li>` have shown up.

Now, since it's a list, you need to iterate through the list. Don't assume that the code will automatically figure out that you're done with the first record and are ready to move on to the next.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//[contains(@id,'listbox')]/li")));
List<WebElement> things = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//[contains(@id,'listbox')]/li");

things.get(0).click();
things.get(1).click();
things.get(2).click();
```

As as example...

Comment: thanks Scott . But here the condition is when I click on first object then first listbox gets displayed to select , after selecting the listbox object closes. Now I click on second object and another listbox gets opened .....here is what I am facing issues . Unable to click on second list box . I tried above code it still says element not found .

Comment: error is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: my second object(having same xpath) gets populate when i click on another object ....and here is where I am getting issue .

Comment: According to your error, the xpath is only finding one matching element. So this doesn't sound like a case of multiple elements having similar xpath (technically, they can't be the same--xpath has a way to differentiate between the first, second, third, and so on instance of similar paths). Please update your question with the actual HTML code so we can better help.

Comment: I got the solution , actually second element was also in list so I added code to get list again and then list(0).get . Thanks all for help .